# ¿Comó medir el tamaño de un array dentro de una función?

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Hola quiero saber como puedo medir/calcular el tamaño de un array que se le pasa como parametro a una función. Solo de array no quiero y no debo utilizar vectores ó simulares.

```
int vecinos(int *p) {
   int i = 0;
   int len = sizeof p / sizeof(*p);
   cout << len; 
   return 0; 
}

int main()
{
  int p[] = { 1,2,3 };
  vecinos(p);
}
```

Comment: Facil, estas en C++, asi que no uses arrays estilo C. Usa `std::array`, este lleva la informacion del el tamaño. O si tienes que usar arrays estilo C, pasa el array por referencia y usa templates para obtener el tamaño.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 
  int p[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    int tamano_del_array = sizeof(p);
    int tamano_del_tipo_de_dato = sizeof(int);
 

    int cantidad_elementos = tamano_del_array / tamano_del_tipo_de_dato;

    cout<<"la cantidad de elementos es: "<<cantidad_elementos<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```